# Why does 'mount' give the error "mount: can't find /mnt/disk"?

Tags: ubuntu, mount

I am trying to following the to mount an img file on ubuntu:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/129305/how-can-i-open-binary-image-files-img

But when I do 'sudo mount -o  test.img  /mnt/disk'

```
 $ sudo mount -o  test.img  /mnt/disk
mount: can't find /mnt/disk in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab
```

Can you please tell me how can fix that?

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to actually give the options to `-o`. Because of that, `mount` interprets "`test.img`" as the options, and not as the disk/image to mount.

```
sudo mount -o loop test.img /mnt/disk
```

Comment: On recent Linuxes, `-o loop` is not necessary anymore: `sudo mount test.img /mnt/disk`

Comment: Thanks. I try that. And it said 'mount: you must specify the filesystem type'. My img is a image file for android. Can you please tell me what filesystem I should use? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the right way to do it would be to convert img file to iso and than mount it as loop device.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1686904

according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357924/how-to-mount-img-file-on-linux-extracted-from-a-modem-firmware)

you forgot to add "loop"